# NodeJs function...Updated

Tags: node.js, function

This works, and returns what is expected:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db/database');
const SQL = require('../db/sql'); 
 
const router = express.Router();
 
// handles url http://.../api
router.get("/api", (req, res, next) => {
    
    db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else
            {
            console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
            connection.query(SQL1, (err, data)=> {
                connection.release(); // return the connection to pool
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                } else
                    {
                        if(data) {
                            return res.status(200).json(data);
                        } else {
                            return res.status(204).json({
                                message:"Data not found."
                                });
                            }
                    } 
                });
            }                  
    });
});
```

When I try to remove the obtain a connection/execute SQL/release the connection/return the results is where I am running into issues.  The executeSql function executes, and logs the results of the sql, but it doesn't see to be returning the results to get route that called it.

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db/database');
const SQL = require('../db/sql'); 
 
const router = express.Router();
 
// handles url http://.../apitest/
router.get("/apitest", (req, res, next) => { 
    const sqlText = SQL1;
    var sqlResults = executeSql(sqlText);
    console.log(`sqlResults: ${sqlResults}`);
    return res.status(200).json(sqlResults);

});


function executeSql(sqlText) {
    db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        else {
            console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
            console.log(`sqlText in executeSql: ${sqlText}`);
            connection.query(sqlText, (err, data) => {
                connection.release(); // return the connection to pool
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                }
                else {
                    if (data) {
                        console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        return "Data not found.";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
 
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question. Hard to tell what the problem is..

Comment: My apologies.  I am not sure how to structure the function, and properly call within the routes. @NicholasSiegmundt

Comment: @geddAdmin whats not working? Whats the error?

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt I am not currently getting an error.  I wasn't sure what the best way to remove the pool.connection and querying portion out to a global level, and be able to call it from within the route.

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt I updated the question, and hopefully, it makes more sense.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: frankly I'm a bit surprised this works at all.  The call to the db to execute the query should be async, the code you're writing is appears to be synchronous and the data returned from connection.query could possibly be undefined if the db call is slow enough.  Anyways, its a bit difficult to tell you how to manage connection pool without seeing the code in `db/database`, and what DB driver/orm you're using.  Connection pool could be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at the code again and re-reading your question it does seem like you aren't respecting the asynchronous nature of javascript and the node environment it works in.  The reason why your execute sql function works and logs out the response is because all of that occurs in the callback:

```
 connection.query(sqlText, (err, data) => {
// ### THIS IS THE CALLBACK WHERE DATA EXISTS ###
   connection.release(); // return the connection to pool
     if (err) {
       return err;
     } else {
     if (data) {
       console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
       return JSON.stringify(data);  // <-- THIS WILL NOT WORK
     }
```

You're expecting `return JSON.stringify(data)` to work here:

```
var sqlResults = executeSql(sqlText);
```

Except because javascript and node is async, the executeSql function is called, and the lines following it are getting executed before executeSql is finished, which is why your route hander is not receiving data in your 2nd code snippet.

May want to look into async/await patterns, Promises, or use good old fashioned callbacks just like your first code snippet.